# FFMPEG Concat Silence & 10 Channel WAV

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, concatenation

I am trying to join together using concat some silence which is generated, and then a WAV file. This works fine when the WAV is mono, stereo, etc. - but goes wrong when we have 10 channels of audio;

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0^|0^|0^|0^|0^|0^|0^|0^|0^|0:durat
ion=0.02 -i "10channel.WAV"  -filter_complex "[1:a] [0:a] concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [
a]" -map [a] -acodec pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -ac 10 "output.wav"

ffmpeg version N-90315-gf706cdda56 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --e
nable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libblur
ay --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-
libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enab
le-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-li
bvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --en
able-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-
libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enabl
e-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --en
able-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enabl
e-avisynth
  libavutil      56.  9.100 / 56.  9.100
  libavcodec     58. 14.100 / 58. 14.100
  libavformat    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavdevice    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavfilter     7. 13.100 /  7. 13.100
  libswscale      5.  0.102 /  5.  0.102
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, lavfi, from 'aevalsrc=0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0:duration=0.02':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 28224 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_f64le, 44100 Hz, 10 channels, dbl, 28224 kb/s
Input #1, wav, from '\\gpsnearline1\000003_gps_offline\01_native\01_rushes\audio
\SR_02BEAR_AND_SWAN\2ACTIVITYT04.WAV':
  Metadata:
    comment         : sSPEED=025.000-ND
                    : sTAKE=04
                    : sUBITS=$00000000
                    : sSWVER=4.00.18
                    : sSCENE=2ACTIVITY
                    : sFILENAME=2ACTIVITYT04.WAV
                    : sTAPE=170518
                    : sCIRCLED=FALSE
                    : sTRK1=MixL
                    : sTRK2=MixR
                    : sTRK3=BOOM
                    : sTRK4=HENRY
                    : sTRK5=SAM
                    : sTRK6=LISA
                    : sTRK7=TONY
                    : sTRK8=JORGE
                    : sTRK9=MARTYN
                    : sTRK10
    encoded_by      : Sound Dev: Mix688 S#NR0316238011
    originator_reference: USSDVNR0316238011170518Fh8CY  01
    date            : 2017-05-18
    creation_time   : 15:43:16
    time_reference  : 2714688001
    coding_history  : A=PCM,F=48000,W=24,M=multi,R=48000,T=10 Ch
                    :
  Duration: 00:04:22.00, bitrate: 11520 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 10 channels
, s32 (24 bit), 11520 kb/s
File '\\Autoingestsd1\ai_cache\GPS\wavtest.wav' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N
] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (pcm_f64le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #1:0 (pcm_s24le) -> concat:in0:a0
  concat -> Stream #0:0 (pcm_s24le)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_aevalsrc_0 @ 0000002f39fecb80] EOF timestamp not reliable
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0000002f3e4323c0] Cannot select channel layout for the link
between filters auto_resampler_0 and Parsed_concat_0.
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0000002f3e4323c0] Unknown channel layouts not supported, try
 specifying a channel layout using 'aformat=channel_layouts=something'.
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

No matter what I do - I either get the unknown layout error, or an unsupported layout error.

Any way to get FFMPEG to not care about the layout, and just do a simple literal 1:1 mapping?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to add silence at the end, just pad it

```
ffmpeg -i "10channel.WAV" -af apad=pad_len=0.02*48000 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -ac 10 "output.wav"
```

Comment: Perfect - simple and obvious when you think about it!! Much appreciated.